# static data member defined in base class(template) but with type of derived class

Tags: c++, templates

i have some code like this:

// Factory.h

```
template <typename TFactoryTable, typename TBaseProduct>
class FactoryTable {
public:
    static TFactoryTable instance;
};

template <typename TFactoryTable, typename TBaseProduct>
TFactoryTable FactoryTable<TFactoryTable, TBaseProduct>::instance;
```

// Foo.h

```
class BaseFoo {};
class FooFactoryTable : public FactoryTable<FooFactoryTable, BaseFoo> {};
```

// Bar.h

```
class BaseBar {};
class BarFactoryTable : public FactoryTable<BarFactoryTable, BaseBar> {};
```

// main.cpp

```
void test() {
    auto& t = FooFactoryTable::instance;
}
```

i put the define of static member "instance" in FactoryTable<>, so that, i can force factory tables (FooFactoryTable, BarFactoryTable,...) to use the same way to define it's singleton. these code compiled well by visual studio 2012(v110), but the editor (IntelliSense not compiler) report an error on FooFactoryTable::instance in test():

```
Error: class "FooFactoryTable" has no member "instance"
```

if i change the declaration & definition of instance to be of type "FactoryTable" (not TFactoryTable), then the editor won't report the error. so i worry that, is this (compile well) a msvc only feature, or a standard c++ feature? because the code's target platform is android and iphone, and need to be compiled by gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellisense gets easily confused by more complex constructs (especially with the preprocessor or templates) and likes to report bogus errors. Like this one. Your code using `TFactoryTable` as the static member type is 100% legal C++.

Comment: I'm curious: wouldn't there be a linker error that there are multiple definitions of `FooFactoryTable::instance` if Foo.h is included in more than 1 compilation units? Or would there multiple "private" instances for each unit, annihilating the use of a singleton?

Comment: @king_nak There will be exactly one instance, and the definition *must* be present in every translation unit which uses it. The compiler/linker have to make it work.

Comment: Ok, nice work of the linker... I know that definitions for templates must occur in every unit, but didn't know that it works this way for statics. Because if there were no templates, the static instance must be defined in *exactly one* unit!